# Convert a character string containing a concatenated set of numbers into a numeric vector in R

Tags: r

I have the following object.

```
object1 <- "c(3:6, 8, 10:13, 16, 21)"
```

I'd like to convert `object1`, which is a character string, into the following numeric vector.

```
object2 <- c(3:6, 8, 10:13, 16, 21)
```

Are there any good solutions? `base` R solutions are preferred but I'm open to anything. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R base solution using `eval`+`parse`

```
> eval(parse(text=object1))
 [1]  3  4  5  6  8 10 11 12 13 16 21
```